# What happens to Mel and Bobbi in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

So I've played that mission where Bobbi makes me dig through ground to reach a warehouse. Mel is also with us.

Then I persuaded Bobbi to leave us instead of fighting the gunmen.

When I revisited the digging sites later in the game, I found Mel just standing there in the tunnel, and doesn't talk to me. Bobbi is nowhere to be found.

So what happened to them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As detailed in the [**Bug List**](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Big_Dig#Bugs) for this quest on the Fallout wiki, it is known that a few scenarios can render Mel to become unresponsive.

It is very likely that you have encountered one of these bugs and unfortunately, the common solution as stated on the wiki is to reload a previous save.

Bobbi owns a house in Goodneighbor - That might be a good place to look.